# Промежуточная обработка данных перед загрузкой в базу данных Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite3

Только начал учить Django. Имеется хэш-функция, которую написал сам и хочу превратить её во что-то полезное. Решил сделать свой сервис для сокращения ссылок. Так вот, куда и как вставить "сухой код" хэш-функции (или, если надо его изменить, то что надо сделать?), чтобы после ввода пользователем ссылки в форму в базу данных попадала сама ссылка, а рядом с ней был соответствующий хэш, то есть чтобы была эта промежуточная обработка строки перед загрузкой в базу данных? Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

> Так вот, куда и как вставить "сухой код" хэш-функции (или, если надо
> его изменить, то что надо сделать?) чтобы после ввода пользователем ссылки в базу данных попадала сама ссылка, а рядом с ней был соответствующий хэш

Его надо вставлять в метод, который обрабатывает обращение из вашей формы. Как делать формы в django - [ссылка на официальный ресурс.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/)

Comment: Про то, как делать формы я уже знаю и работал с ними. Могу сделать форму, где пользователь что-то вводит и это что-то отправляется в базу данных. Не могли бы Вы рассказать больше о этом методе?

Comment: Добавляйте в задачу ваш код, отталкиваясь от вашего кода я предложу решение вашей проблемы.